# On non-isomorphic and isomorphic Steiner Triple System!

Tags: combinatorial-designs

in this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) page, it says the following

> Up to isomorphism, the STS(7) and STS(9) are unique, there are two STS(13)s, 80 STS(15)s, and 11,084,874,829 STS(19)s

Now, in [wolframe](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html) page it says the following

> The numbers of nonisomorphic Steiner triple systems S(v) of orders v=7, 9, 13, 15, 19, ... (i.e., 6k+1,3) are 1, 1, 2, 80, 11084874829, ...

it seems that "up to isomorphism" is the same as "nonisomorphism". According to what I know is that "isomorphic" means that we can map something to something else. But, "non-isomorphic" means that we cannot map something to something else. Now, in could you tell me what is different between "up to isomorphism" and "non-isomorphism"? Are they mean the same?

Suppose we have STS(7). Now, since number of non-isomorphic is 1 in STS(7), there is only one design in STS(7) that cannot be mapped to any other designs of STS(7) among all 6! of different permutation of different mapping, Is what I understand correct?!! In fact I would like to know how to show that STS(7) have only one isomorphism? Is it a theorem or just searching among all permutation of different mapping?!!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting things "up to isomorphism" means finding the number of "nonisomorphic" things. Let me take $S(7)$ as an example (and abbreviate $STS(v)$ to just $S(v)$, as in the Wolfram link).

Here's a sample $S(7)$ (rows are blocks in the design; so $\{1,2,4\}$ is in there, etc.):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1 & 2 &   & 4 &   &   &   \\\hline
  & 2 & 3 &   & 5 &   &   \\\hline
  &   & 3 & 4 &   & 6 &   \\\hline
  &   &   & 4 & 5 &   & 7 \\\hline
1 &   &   &   & 5 & 6 &   \\\hline
  & 2 &   &   &   & 6 & 7 \\\hline
1 &   & 3 &   &   &   & 7 \\\hline
\end{array}

Here's another $S(7)$:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  &   &   &   & 5 & 6 & 7 \\\hline
  &   & 3 & 4 &   &   & 7 \\\hline
1 & 2 &   &   &   &   & 7 \\\hline
  & 2 &   & 4 &   & 6 &   \\\hline
1 &   & 3 &   &   & 6 &   \\\hline
  & 2 & 3 &   & 5 &   &   \\\hline
1 &   &   & 4 & 5 &   &   \\\hline
\end{array}

Now, these aren't literally the same; $\{5, 6, 7\}$ is a block in the second, not the first. But, they are isomorphic. Let's define a map $\varphi \colon [7] \to [7]$, where $[7]$ is our shorthand for $\{1, 2, \ldots, 7\}$.

$$\varphi = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 4 & 6 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So $1 \mapsto 2,\, 2 \mapsto 1,\ 3 \mapsto 5$, etc. This map will take lines in the first $S(7)$ to lines in the second $S(7)$ (I found the map by just drawing the Fano planes; this is probably the easiest way to see it's an isomorphism!).

So here, our two $S(7)$'s are isomorphic.

> Suppose we have STS(7). Now, since number of non-isomorphic is 1 in STS(7), there is only one design in STS(7) that cannot be mapped to any other designs of STS(7) among all 6! of different permutation of different mapping, Is what I understand correct?!!

Not exactly -- actually, kind of the exact opposite $\ddot \smile$. To say that there's only 1 nonisomorphic design $S(7)$ means that if you have two $S(7)$'s, they *must* be isomorphic to each other (as in our example). So starting with any 1 $S(7)$ design $\mathcal{D}$, there's an isomorphism $\varphi \colon \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}'$ to any other $S(7)$ design $\mathcal{D}'$.

Instead of saying "there are $n$ nonisomorphic $S(v)$ designs", it might be more clear to say that "there are $n$ isomorphism classes of $S(v)$ designs." This means that we can build a list of $n$ of those $S(v)$ designs such that

- None of them are isomorphic to anything else on that list; they're pairwise "nonisomorphic."
- Given *any* other $S(v)$ design, it must be isomorphic to something on our list of size $n$.

In the $S(7)$ case, our list is just a single $S(7)$ design and any other $S(7)$ design must be isomorphic to ours.

> In fact I would like to know how to show that STS(7) have only one isomorphism? Is it a theorem or just searching among all permutation of different mapping?!!

What you want to show is that if you have any two $S(7)$ designs, they must be isomorphic (or, that there's just one isomorphism *class* of $S(7)$ designs).

Here's [a proof](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/comb/ch8s.pdf) by Cameron (problem 3) that $S(7)$ is unique up to isomorphism, requiring essentially no theorems on designs or geometry. It basically constructs an isomorphism from any $S(7)$ to a fixed $S(7)$.

I'm sure that this result follows from theorems in various fields as well. People (not me, unfortunately -- maybe someone else will come along) know a *lot* about combinatorial designs, and I suspect there's a more high-brow proof that $S(7)$ is unique, up to isomorphism (meaning, all $S(7)$ designs are isomorphic to one another).